# Login failed to connect Database using windows account?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7

I have deployed a asp.net web application in iis 7.5 (remote server) as "windows authentication"

```
...
 <system.web>
    ...
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="false"/>
    ...
 </system.web>
```

and application running on "NetworkService" identity.

and my connectionstring has `<add key="dbKey" value="Server=Test_Server$123;Database=Master;Trusted_Connection=True;"/>`

While I am trying to connect database from code it is throwing `Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'`

Code:

```
Public Shared Function GetServerConnection(connectionString As String) As ServerConnection
    Dim serverCon As New Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection(Connection(connectionString))
    serverCon.Connect() 'Error is showing here
    Return serverCon
End Function
```

**How can user can connect to database with his windows credentials to Database and read tables data?**

Comment: Why are you using `appSettings` instead of the purpose built `connectionStrings` section?

Comment: And in regards to the actual question - did you setup SQL Server to allow windows authentication?

Comment: Yes, I  have setup SQL Server to allow windows authentication

Comment: Have you also ensured `NetworkService` is a valid login on the server?

Comment: Yes, that is true.. I am able to connect DB server from remote server where I deployed web application...

Comment: What is `Connecection(connectionString)`?

Comment: Public Shared Function Connecection(connectionString As String) As SqlConnection

            Dim con As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Return con
        End Function

Comment: `Connecection(connectionString)` is mispelled - "Connecection" should just be "Connection" (I imagine that's not your problem, but it bothers me).

Comment: thats not a bigdeal.. its my typo.. But that is not an issue...